# How to filter get result based on two parameters passed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a drop down list with all customer names as checkbox. User can check the box to select multiple customer. I also have one textbox where user can key in customer name. If user select Customer A,B,C from dropdown and did not enter anything in the textbox, result should show A,B,C. If user select A,B,C from drop down and enter A in textbox, the statement should check whether A is selected in the drop down also and result should be A only. This is my SQL statement. Currently if I select A,B,C and enter A, it still gives me A,B,C. How can change it if I select A,B,C and enter A, it should give me only A. @CLIST holds A,B,C with comma as separator. @CNAME holds A that user key in.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.ID, A.NAME, A.DID  
INTO #TMPTBL
FROM MY_LIST A (NOLOCK) 
WHERE  (@CLIST = '' AND (@CNAME='' OR  (A.ID + A.NAME) like '%'+@CNAME+'%'))
OR (A.ID in (SELECT ListItem FROM GetSplitList(',',@CLIST)))
```

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags

Comment: is `@CLIST` empty if `@CNAME` is filled? If so, and you manipulate the parameters anyway by emptying the list, why not just always send @CLIST, but if the textbox is filled, send its value instead of the list value? Hope the sentence still makes sense :D

Comment: I cannot do that, if I select A,B,C and pass D in the box then no result should return.

Comment: No, but then only pass D, but as the `@CList` parameter. Removing the `@CName` completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is flawed, for each parameter you need to check `@param = '' OR @param is-match`

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
    A.ID, A.NAME, A.DID  
INTO #TMPTBL
FROM MY_LIST A
WHERE (
    @CNAME = '' OR
    A.ID + A.NAME LIKE '%' + @CNAME + '%'
) AND (
    @CLIST = '' OR
    A.ID IN (SELECT ListItem FROM GetSplitList(',',@CLIST))
);
```

> Side notes:
> Don't splatter your code with `NOLOCK`, it's not a go-faster switch
> Consider using a Table Valued Parameter instead of the comma-separated list